# I am coding a MMORPG using Node.js, Express and HTML. The player can only move left

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am coding a MMORPG using Node.js, Express and HMTL. I am working on keyboard interactivity but when I load my game only pressing D works, so the player can only move right. No idea why this is, can anyone help? I have below my app.js and index.html code. I have tried using various different keys, just not sure why moving right works and nothing else. Perhaps a syntax error I'm not seeing, thanks in advance.

```
app.js:
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

//8080? Port number
serv.listen(8080);
console.log("Server started");

var SOCKET_LIST = {};
var PLAYER_LIST = {};

var Player = function(id){
    var self = {
        x:250,
        y:250,
        id:id,
        number:"" + Math.floor(10 * Math.random()),
      pressingRight:false,
      pressingLeft:false,
      pressingUp:false,
      pressingDown:false,
      maxSpd:5
    };
    self.updatePosition = function(){
        if(self.pressingRight)
            self.x += self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingLeft)
            self.x -= self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingUp)
            self.y -= self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingDown)
            self.y += self.maxSpd;
    };
    return self;
};

var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.id = Math.random();
    SOCKET_LIST[socket.id] = socket;

    var player = Player(socket.id);
    PLAYER_LIST[socket.id] = player;

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        delete SOCKET_LIST[socket.id];
        delete PLAYER_LIST[socket.id];
    });

    socket.on('keyPress', function(data){
        if(data.inputId === 'left')
            player.pressingLeft = data.state;
        else if(data.inputId === 'right')
            player.pressingRight = data.state;
        else if(data.inputId === 'down')
            player.pressingDown = data.state;
        else if(data.inputId === 'up')
            player.pressingUp = data.state;
    });
});

setInterval(function(){
    var pack = [];
for(var i in PLAYER_LIST){
    var player = PLAYER_LIST[i];
    player.updatePosition();
    pack.push({
        x:player.x,
        y:player.y,
        number:player.number
    });
    }
    for (var i in SOCKET_LIST){
    var socket = SOCKET_LIST[i];
    socket.emit('newPositions', pack);
    }
},100/25);

index.html:
<canvas id="ctx" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:1px solid#000000;"></canvas>

<script src="
        https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"
        ></script>
<script>

        var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = '30px Arial';

    var socket = io();

    socket.on('newPositions', function(data){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000);
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        ctx.fillText(data[i].number,data[i].x, data[i].y);
    });

    document.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode === 68) //d
            socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'right', state:true});
        else if(event.keyCode === 83) //s
            socket.emimt('keyPress', {inputId:'down', state:true});
        else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
            socket.emimt('keyPress', {inputId:'left', state:true});
        else if(event.keyCode === 85) //u
            socket.emimt('keyPress', {inputId:'up', state:true});
    };

        document.onkeyup = function(event){
            if(event.keyCode === 68) //d
                socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId:'right', state:false});
            else if(event.keyCode === 83) //s
                socket.emimt('keyPress', {inputId:'down', state:false});
            else if(event.keyCode === 65) //a
                socket.emimt('keyPress', {inputId:'left', state:false});
            else if(event.keyCode === 85) //u
                socket.emimt('keyPress', {inputId:'up', state:false});
        };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have `socket.emit` on pressing right.  The other directions have a typo: `socket.emimt`

:-P